# Proof verification: the complement of a convex and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I tried to prove the following

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ bounded and convex. Then $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus X$ is connected.

Proof:

I will prove that $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus X$ is path-connected which implies it is connected.

Let $x \ne y \in\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus X$. Since $X$ is bounded there exists $r>0$ s.t. $X \subset B(\mathbf{0},r)$ and $x,y \in B(\mathbf{0},r)$.

Define for every $z,v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ $\gamma_{z,v} :=\{w \in \mathbb{R^2} : w = z+tv |t \in \mathbb{R}^+ \}$ (it is the half-line starting from $z$ with direction $v$).

Clearly for every $v\ne \mathbf{0}$ , $\gamma_{x,v} \cap \partial B(\mathbf{0},r) \ne \emptyset$ ($t= r-||x||$).

There exists $v\in \mathbb{R^2}$ : $\gamma_{x,v} \cap X = \emptyset$:

if not, choose $b \in \mathbb{R}^2$, then $x_1 \in \gamma_{x,b} \cap X \ne \emptyset$ and $x_2 \in \gamma_{x,-b} \cap X \ne \emptyset$ and then $x \in \{tx_1+(1-t)x_2 | t \in [0;1]$ } which implies $X$ is not convex.

Then choose $v_1$ satisfying $\gamma_{x,v_1} \cap X = \emptyset$. The same can be done with $y$, so we have $\gamma_{y,v_2} \cap X = \emptyset$.

Then we have the path

1. from $x$ to $\gamma_{x,v_1} \cap \partial B(\mathbf{0},r)$
2. from $\gamma_{x,v_1} \cap \partial B(\mathbf{0},r)$ to $\gamma_{x,v_2} \cap  \partial B(\mathbf{0},r)$
3. from $\gamma_{x,v_2} \cap \partial B(\mathbf{0},r)$ to y

which is completely outside $X$.

(I know I should write a function $\alpha : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2\setminus X$ s.t. $\alpha(0)=x$ and $\alpha(1)=y$ but I think it is clear how it is made and I do not want to add further notation)

Comment: When you proved that $\gamma_{x,v}\cap B(\mathbf{0},r)\neq\emptyset$, why didn't you just take $t=0$?

Comment: You don't need convexity, since the only separating sub spaces of $\Bbb{R}^2$ are unbounded.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry, I meant $\partial B(\mathbf{0},r)=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : ||x||=r \} $...

Comment: @S.vanNigtevecht He can't.

Comment: Fixed again, too much $\partial$. Now it should be ok...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you said, for any point $P$ outside $X$ and any line trough $P$, one of the halflines determined by $P$ does not intersect $X$. I guess it's clearer if you take only lines in a certain direction ( say vertical), and then contain $X$ in a big square ( think of all the vertical slices). So from any point outside $X$ you can reach either the top of the bottom side. Works in any dimension $\ge 2$.

Comment: Yes, this was what I tried to write formally (instead of a square I used a circle)..So is my proof ok?

Comment: @Bremen000: yep, looks great!